# How to add touch event listener in Cocos2dx 3.1?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I used following code to add listener method to a Button in cocos2dx:

```
button->addTouchEventListener(this, toucheventselector(HomeScene::doSomething));
```

But since Cocos2dx 3.1 both toucheventselector and addTouchEventListener is depreciated. There is :

```
void addTouchEventListener(ccWidgetTouchCallback callback);
```

I can't make it work - I tried every macro I could find - callfuncO_selector, CC_CALLBACK etc. I just don't know how to point to my method that looks like this:

```
void HomeScene::doSomething(Ref *pSender, Widget::TouchEventType type);
```

Failed to find any clue from Google, forum, git, change log, tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CC_CALLBACK_2 macro.

Comment: @filip please write here more details. I have the same problem and don't know how to solve. I thought I should use `Widget::ccWidgetTouchCallback`?

Comment: As Lazar suggested, you should use CC_CALLBACK_2 macro instead of ccWidgetTouchCallback since there is no such thing yet in Cocos2dx 3.1 AFIK.

Comment: @filip thank for your answer. Do you know if it is possible to set as a listener not a class method, but a lambda function?

Comment: @Narek - Yes, you can use lambdas as callbacks: `EventListener* listener = EventListenerCustom::create(eventName, [this](EventCustom* e){ /* do something */ });`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I usually subclass my button and add listeners to it. Example: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_To_Subclass_Sprite_And_Add_Event_Listeners

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
button->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(HomeScene::doSomething,this));
```

to solve this issue :-)